# Календарь недельной нагрузки → календарь месячной нагрузки через электронные таблицы

Tags: excel, дата, календарь, open-office

Ищу решение для упрощения перевода календаря недельной нагрузки преподавателей в календарь месячной, желательно посредством электронных таблиц (Excel, OO Calc и т. д.) Результат я представляю себе так:
На первом листе размещается недельный график распределения нагрузки (вводится вручную):

```
                            Дни недели
ФИО     Понедельник Вторник Среда Четверг Пятница Суббота
Иванов       5                4      3       4
Петров                 4      8      2       5       3
Сидоров      4         3      2      7       6
```

А на последующих листах — высчитываемые на основании графика недельной нагрузки графики распределения месячной нагрузки по числам, причём данные на каждое число берутся по соответствующим дням недели. Например для мая 2016 (начинается с воскресенья):

```
               Числа
ФИО     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 …
Иванов     5     4  3  4        5    …
Петров        4  8  2  5  3        4 …
Сидоров    4  3  2  7  6        4  3 …
```

Как можно добиться такого результата? Алгоритмически задача не сложная, но не знаю с какой стороны к ней подступиться в электронных таблицах.

Comment: Нужно использовать скриптовый язык. Для Excel это Visual Basic, для Libre Office, других таблиц что-то подобное будет.

Comment: можно и формулами, только громоздко слишком

Comment: @AivanF, А список преподавателей с листа с недельной нагрузкой можно формулой воспроизводить на каждом листе месячной нагрузки? Если да, то какой? (По сути — копировать все значение в столбце, сколько их есть).

Comment: @rdorn, а через формулы — как?

Comment: ну вот, заставили вспомнить давно забытое

Answer (score 1):

Excel под руками только русский, поэтому названия функций пишу на русском. Сопоставление русских и английских названий не сложно нагуглить. Итак начнем.

Будут нужны следующие функции:

**ПОИСКПОЗ(искомое, столбец или строка для поиска)** - определяет относительную позицию элемента

**ДАТА(год; месяц; день)** - возвращает числовое значение даты

**ДЕНЬНЕД(дата в числовом формате; формат)** - возвращает номер дня недели, формат = 2, в нашем случае

**ГПР(искомое; диапазон поиска; номер строки)** - прикольная поисковая функция, которая ищет указанное значение в первой строке диапазона поиска и возвращает значение из ячейки в указанной строке и том же столбце что и найденное значение.

Подробные описания функций есть во встроенной справке Excel.

В итоге у меня получилась такая формула:

```
=ГПР(ДЕНЬНЕД(ДАТА(год; месяц; день); 2); диапазон поиска; ПОИСКПОЗ(преподаватель; столбец преподавателей в таблице недельной нагрузки)+смещение))
```

Несколько замечаний: дни недели должны быть записаны числами (пн=1...вс=7). смещение в формуле нужно подбирать руками исходя из размещения диапазона поиска для функции `ГПР()`

Ну и для наглядности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь поправить ссылки на ячейки, соответствующим образом, труда не составит.